"En toile de fond" vs "au second plan" to mean "in the background"?
I've asked ChatGPT but its explanation didn't quite do it for me. It seems to me like the two are very close to interchangeable, but are they really? Are there nuances between these two expressions or are they synonyms?

They aren't often interchangeable.
Au second plan is part of a layer categorization that starts with au premier plan and can have more than two layers.

Premier plan - deuxième plan
Premier plan - deuxième plan - troisième plan
Premier plan - deuxième plan - troisième plan - [...]

That means the deuxième plan is the backgound only if two layers are considered. To make sure you talk about the background, better to talk about the arrière-plan which is always the one in the back.
Toile de fond used to mean the set in a theater, an actual canvas where the settings are painted, a painted backdrop but nowadays, it is much more often used figuratively to mean something that happens for a longer period that the events that are described.
It looks like backdrop can be used the same figurative way in English:

Their love affair began against a backdrop of war.1
Leur histoire d'amour débuta avec la guerre comme toile de fond.

Cases where toile de fond can't be used are:

Passer au deuxième plan (cease to be the focus of attention)
You can't say "passer en toile de fond".

In IT, a background job is often called une tâche en arrière-plan or sometimes une tâche de fond, never "tâche en toile de fond" again.


1 Quoted from the Cambridge Dictionary.

It seems like a better translation for toile de fond is actually backdrop rather than background, similar though they may be.

@temporary_user_name Indeed, I already mentioned 'painted backdrop' as a translation for toile de fond in my reply.

The thing is backdrop or background would be two possibilities. When in politics, we say x is a backdrop for y, we don't say painted.

@Lambie Je ne comprends sur quoi porte ta première phrase, deux possibilités de quoi ? Qu'est-ce qui te fait penser que je dirais painted backdrop dans un contexte politique ?

A theater backdrop is just that. There's no need to say painted.

@Lambie Okay, there is no need to say it but is it wrong or you just don't like it?

As a translation for the term toile de fond, adding painted would be inaccurate.

Good idea to allow a humble human to try to answer!

"En toile de fond" is the closest to "in the background", as well as "en arrière-plan" which is the literal translation

"Au second plan" generally implies that a "premier plan" has been introduced, with emphasis on the comparison between the two


Example:

Regarde le paysage: on peut voir le coucher de soleil en arrière-plan. // A partir de demain je commence le basket, la course et la danse, avec en toile de fond toujours le travail.

Both put emphasis on the background's existence (in a landscape context for the first sentence, and daily activities for the second one).

Dans cette ville, depuis que le cinéma a ouvert ses portes, le théâtre a été relégué au second plan.

This other example compares the former "premier plan" (the traditional theater) with the one that replaced it (the cinema). Therefore, something got pushed back to "second plan". Even with no formal comparison, this is the idea behind this expression's use.

au second plan in 2) would be relegated to a secondary role. So, au premier plan and au second plan can be main role and secondary role. When the context is not the theater, for example.
